# Find Address bound from index in PHP

Tags: php, algorithm

I am having doubt implementing this algorithm in PHP. I have few address bounds( or ranges ). The size of the address bound vary ( as shown in the image). Now, I have a key element. I need to find, which address bound, does the key element lie.

I am currently using multiple if statements to compare, add the bound length. I am sure, there is a better way to do it. Any idea how it can be implemented.

I am not looking for code( even though it helps :) ). Just the idea on how it can be implemented, would be helpful .

[image]

Comment: Key element references to a particular address bound?

Comment: For instance, here key=10 lies in bound3. If key=2, it lies in bound1

Answer (score 1):

A way to do the job, is to define a 2-dimensional array, which contains the bounds:

```php
<?php
$bounds = array();
$bounds[0] = array(1, 1, 1);
$bounds[1] = array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
$bounds[2] = array(1, 1, 1);
// ...
?>
```

And an other array which contains the index of the bound depending on the key:

```
<?php
$indexes = array(0, 0, 0,
     1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
     2, 2, 2,
     3, 3, 3, 3,
     4);
?>
```

Then, assuming `$key = 10`, `$bounds[$indexes[$key]]` refers to `$bounds[2]` which is `array(1, 1, 1);`

Here you are duplicating data but this is a `O(1)` algorithm.

---

**An other way** (the best if you don't manipulate a *ton* of data), without duplicating data (but `O(n)` complexity), is to go through the `$bounds` array:

```
<?php
for($key = 10, $i = 0; $key >= 0; $key -= count($bounds[$i]), ++$i);
?>
```

Here, `$bounds[$i-1]` refers to `$bounds[2]`.

Comment: You're saving a lot of data. If you're going to hardcode these, why not just make an array that says which key is in which bound? THat will not take up more space, and is equally fast. I think we can all agree that saving the bounds as an array is not a real smart solution, but as it seems equivalent to above, this solution might also be a bit  off?

Comment: This is another solution you are right. But I wanted to show, in my answer, that the second way is better.